# How to translate " This is a required field. " in magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, localisation, translate

How to translate " This is a required field. " in magento 2. I was change in file csv but it not working, please help me!

Comment: Did you upgrade the code after this?

Comment: yes, i was upgraded

Comment: Are you use theme csv file or module ?

Comment: yes, i used csv but only it not translate

Comment: update in vendor module csv file

Comment: yes, i was updated, it not workinggggggg

Comment: deploy the code

Comment: yes, i was deploy